# Expected value and variance for the changed range

Tags: self-study, variance, expected-value, range

I have a distribution with E[X]=-8 and Var[X]=60 and the range of the data [-256,255].
I want to convert this distribution of range [0,256] taking the absolute value of data set. What will be the expected value and variance for this system?
Any helpful hint related to it is appreciated.
Thanks
Farhana

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 3):

There's not enough information to answer.

Consider these two cases:

a) $x_1$ =  -14.708204, -14.708204,  -1.291796,  -1.291796

b) $x_2$ =  -17.486833,  -8.000000,  -8.000000,   1.486833

both sets of data fulfill your conditions on the mean and variance but their absolute values have different means and variances.

There's an infinity of other cases. How can we know which one you want?

Comment: I have a large data set and don't want to perform extensive operation to calculate the mean and variance for absolute data set. Is this possible to somehow get a rough result from the above mentioned mean and variance?

Comment: With only that information and no other assumptions? You should be able to develop bounds on the mean and variance, but they may not be very tight. It may be better to take a small random sample of your large data set and estimate from that.